# Javascript function not finding elements in modal window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onchange, modalpopupextender

I have a modal popup which contains a TextBox and Label as per the below.
I am simply trying to get the Label to display the TextBox text as it is entered:

```
<input runat="server" id="txtNominalAmount" type="text" onchange="Test()" />
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="nothing"></asp:Label>

<script>
    function Test() {
        var x = document.getElementById('<%= txtNominalAmount.ClientID %>');
        var y = document.getElementById('<%= lblTest.ClientID %>');
        y.innerText = x.innerText;
    }
</script>
```

However, before the modal window is even opened, I get the below error at the line where I am setting `var x`:

> `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

So I then tried to do the function as:

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtNominalAmount.ClientID %>').onchange = function Test()..........
```

But again I get the same error message before the modal window has even opened.

I feel this should be very simple but am struggling so if anyone can see where I am going wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: txtNominalAmount.ClientID %>  What is client ID here??

Comment: Well it doesn't appear to be finding it - so nothing,

Comment: then that might be the issue??

Comment: Yes it is the issue. My question is why is it not finding it?

Comment: txtNominalAmount is the input element ID. with that id your trying to access ClientID which I couldn't see in your code

Comment: How it will find ??

Comment: Each control/element gets assigned a unique ClientID automatically so that you can refer to that control/element on the client side. So when I refer to `txtNominalAmount.ClientID` in JavaScript, it should know that I am looking at that TextBox.

Comment: you should have tag asp in that question, I'm not much familier with ASP Sorry

Comment: I don't like too much of '<%= txtNominalAmount.ClientID %>' practice, I use to set ClietIdMode="Static".. This keep the component ID as the same on the client layer and you can access directly the ID in javascript without these ASP tags. I suggest you to open the browser console in runtime and run each component javascript, if it's correct you'll see an object representation of that or undefined. Inspect their IDs in the browser console markup view.